# Lighttpd to include IP address in error.log

Tags: ssl, lighttpd, logging

I have lighttpd/1.4.31 (ssl) on Debian 7.6 and I would for the standard error.log to include the IP address of the host which caused the error.
Is it possible? The accesslog.format directive allows customisation for access logs, but I can't find a suitable option for error logs.

I am mainly interested in these SSL errors

```
(connections.c.305) SSL: 1 error:1407609C:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:http request
(connections.c.305) SSL: 1 error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:no shared cipher
(connections.c.305) SSSL: 1 error:140760FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:unknown protocol
(connections.c.1715) SSL (error): 5 -1 104 Connection reset by peer
(connections.c.1715) SSL (error): 5 -1 32 Broken pipe
```